# Iframe and Viewport

Tags: html, viewport

I am writing from Brazil.
I participated in this forum in Portuguese, but I did not solve my problem. I hope my english doesn't get too bad.

Well, after much research, I made my HP with an Iframe.

I know a little bit of Html and that's all. I've tried using PHP by copying the famous "Include", but ... I gave up.

I have many pages and the Menu on one side makes it easy to access on the other side.

My site is made up of an "index.html" page that is on the left of the screen and on the right are the content, according to what the user clicks on the Menu.

On desktops, the site works well.

In Smartphones, the appearance is even reasonable and goes something like this:

[image: Smartphone Appearance-1]

---

I read that Google has announced that it will prioritize indexing for mobile-friendly pages.

Well, I put the meta tag in the head of index.html :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Then the problems began. The site looked like this:

[image: Smartphone Appearance-2]

---

The same Meta Tag has also been placed on all content to the right, but ... doesn't solve the problems.

---

Just to complement, the "index.html" containing the Blue Menu on the left looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>

<title>Ciencia,Reportagens, Kardec</title>

<META http-equiv="Content-Language" CONTENT="pt-br">

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="utf-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0 maximum-scale=1.0">

(...)

<style type="text/css">

html, body {

    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}

 iframe { top:0; width:auto; left:auto; height:100%; border:none; background:#ffffff; }

div {
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navcontainer
{
position: fixed;
top: 2px;
bottom: 0px;
background: #0000CD; /*Edite a cor de fundo*/
border-right: 10px solid #696969;
width: 23.1%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0.9em 1;
font-family: georgia, serif;
font-size: 23px;
text-align: left;
font-weight: bold;
overflow-y: auto;
.contentFullFixed{
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
}
}

ul#navlist
{
text-align: center;
list-style: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 90%;
}

ul#navlist li
{
display: block;
margin:  5;
padding: 0;
height: 6%;
padding-top: 0.1em;
}

ul#navlist li a
{
display: block;
width: 190px;

border-width: 4px;
border-color: #fff #8470FF #ccc #fff;
border-style: solid;
color: #000000;
text-decoration: none;
background: #1E90FF; /*Edite a cor de fundo*/
}

#navcontainer>ul#navlist li a { width: auto; }

ul#navlist li#active a
{
background: ##1E90FF; /*Edite a cor de fundo*/
color: #000000;
}

.selected {
    background-color : #fff000;
}

ul#navlist li a:hover {color: #FFFFFF}

ul#navlist li a:active
{
color: #FFF;
background: #B0C4DE;
border-color: #000000 #fff #fff #ccc;

}

#conteudo {
     width: 75.7%;
     position: relative;
     height: 100%;
     text-align: center;
}

    a:hover { color: green}    
    A:link {text-decoration:none}
    A:visited {text-decoration:none}
    A:hover {text-decoration:underline}
    A:active {text-decoration:underline}

iframe {
    border: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
}

img{
display: block;
margin: 30 auto;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>

(...)

<div id="navcontainer" style="border: 5px solid #696969; float: left;">

<ul id="navlist">

<li><a href="prin.html"  target="conteudo">Início</a></li>

<li><a href="textos.html"  target="conteudo">Textos</a></li>

(...)

(...)

</ul>
</div>

<!--  I THINK THE PROBLEM IS HERE :  -->

<div id="conteudo" style="float: right;" class="spaceWrap">

<iframe class="viewPort" name="conteudo" src="prin.html" align="right"></iframe></div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

Could you help?

Thank you in advance.

Jeff

Answer (score 1):

After much research, I ended up finding the solution for those who, without much experience, ends up using Iframes.

We know that GoogleBot has been giving mobile priority in its indexing.

What Google itself recommends is the inclusion of the Meta Tag:

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

But this only works well for sites that do **NOT** have Iframes.

After months of research I found a **VERY SIMPLE ADD-ON** that definitely solves this problem.

Just add, at the end of the Meta Tag above, the following: viewport-fit = cover .... (!!!)

Then it will look like this:

```
<meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover”>
```

**I just don't understand why Google didn't warn you about this.** It took months of research, contacts with Forums, emails to experts, etc., etc. And yet I could only find out in a Blog comment.

On this site, they even recommend placing height resizing as well: height = device-height

And so, we have the complete Meta Tag with Viewport for Iframes:

```
<meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1, height=device-height, viewport-fit=cover”>
```

I hope so much searching time will be for other people who have gone through this.

Thank you.

Jeff